# I get "Boot error" while i try to boot my pc with a live usb, any help?

Tags: live-usb

I am trying to install ubuntu 12.04 (clean install) on a system that already has 11.10. But while i insert the usb and try to boot from it get "Boot error" on a black screen.

I previously installed 11.10 on the system from usb; so it means that my motherboard supports booting from usb-device.

Any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not in Ubuntu or Live USB creator softwares. The problem is in ur BIOS settings.

Go to BIOS boot menu.

Search for 'USB Mass Storage Emulation type'.

Default:`<Auto>`

Change it to:`<All Fixed Disc>`

or something similar

Comment: thanks a lot; i was able to install by making the suggested changes to BIOS.

Comment: i am new to bounties.. I have accepted your answer but I am not sure how do i give the bounty to you.